# Difference of records from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have table from which I am fetching records for two time interval as written below.

```
Query1:

select distinct(Id) 
from dbo.tableA 
where datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 24

Query2:
select distinct(Id) 
from dbo.tableA 
where datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 48
and datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) > 24
```

The query1 returns 50 records and query2  returns 45 records.
After this I want to find those records which which are not present in query2 but present in query1. Can anybody suggest me how to do this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no intersection here. Query 1 lists time <24, and query 2 lists which are >24.

Comment: @bonsvr: I'm assuming that `Id`, despite its name, is not a unique key for the table. (Otherwise `distinct(Id)` wouldn't make sense, either.) There could therefore be some overlap in `Id`s between the two queries, even though no individual table records can overlap.

Comment: @ruakh : yeah its not primary key Id can be repeated multiple number of times.

Comment: @bonsvr: there is no intersection between query1 and query2.

Comment: If there's no intersection, query1 alone would give the records that are not present in query2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `EXCEPT` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT Id
  FROM dbo.tableA
 WHERE datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 24
EXCEPT
SELECT Id
  FROM dbo.tableA
 WHERE datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 48
  AND datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) > 24
;
```

(Note: I got rid of the `DISTINCT`s, because `EXCEPT` does that implicitly; but if you prefer to leave the `DISTINCT`s in there, for clarity's sake, you absolutely can.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to calculate the set difference, so you can use `EXCEPT`:

```
select distinct(Id) 
from dbo.tableA 
where datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 24
EXCEPT
select distinct(Id) 
from dbo.tableA 
where datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) < 48
and datediff(hour, dtCreate, getdate()) > 24
```